# How do I build a CSV with data returned from multiple API calls in Python?

Tags: python, api, csv, data-structures

I'd like to build a CSV file combining data from multiple API calls.  I'm okay with basic Python, and I can call the API, extract the JSON data, and write data to CSV.  Where I need help is efficiently merging the data so I can write it out to CSV once the data extraction is finished.

This is what the data looks like straight from an API request:

```
{u'dateTime': u'2011-03-28', u'value': u'2298'},
{u'dateTime': u'2011-03-29', u'value': u'2322'},
{u'dateTime': u'2011-03-30', u'value': u'2309'},
{u'dateTime': u'2011-03-31', u'value': u'2224'},
{u'dateTime': u'2011-04-01', u'value': u'2763'},
{u'dateTime': u'2011-04-02', u'value': u'3543'},
```

So I'd be looking at merging lots of this together:

```
>APICALL1
2011-03-28,2298
2011-03-29,2322
2011-03-30,2309

>APICALL2
2011-03-28,432
2011-03-29,0
2011-03-30,444
```

Each API call result looks pretty much the same: a date and value.  The date is always formatted the same, so that is our common element.

For a given date and value, there may be no value or 0 returned, so I need to be able to account for the case where there is no data.

The ideal output would look something like this:

```
2011-03-28,2298,432,23952,765,31
2011-03-29,2322,0,432353,766,31
2011-03-30,2309,444,2343923,0,32
2011-03-31,2224,489,3495,765,33
```

I have about 15 calls to make, and each return response contains approximately 800 rows of data (800 days, essentially, growing by 1 row per day into the future).  I need to run this a few times per day, so I am concerned about efficiency to some degree as this grows larger.  Unfortunately, the historical data can change, so I need to rebuild the whole list every time I run the command.  However, the historical data changes infrequently and its only a small percent change, so if there is efficiency to be had in only updating the data, I'm open to that.

One option I know I could make work is just writing everything to the CSV file from the first API call and then re-open the file and write more data to the CSV for each subsequent call (i.e., 15 separate reads and writes to the CSV per program execution).  That doesn't sound very efficient to me.

Should I use SQLite in memory for building the data set and then dump it out to CSV at the end?  Is a list of lists better?  I'm not strong on SQL, although I do know enough to be dangerous if it's the right way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pandas` library for that.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

# Simulation of return values from the calls
calls = [
    [
        {u'dateTime': u'2011-03-28', u'value': u'2298'},
        {u'dateTime': u'2011-03-29', u'value': u'2322'},
        {u'dateTime': u'2011-03-30', u'value': u'2309'},
    ],
    [
        {u'dateTime': u'2011-03-28', u'value': u'28'},
        {u'dateTime': u'2011-03-29', u'value': u'22'},
        {u'dateTime': u'2011-03-30', u'value': u'09'},
    ]
]

# Create an initial empty data frame
df = pd.DataFrame()
# Make the consecutive calls
for i, call in enumerate(calls):
    # Create the new DataFrame from the data you got
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(call).set_index('dateTime')
    # Rebane the column to avoid collision
    df_new.rename(columns={'value': 'value_%s' % i}, inplace=True)
    # Merge it with the current data frame
    df = pd.concat([df, df_new], axis=1)
# Save data to file (I'm using here the sys.stdout, just
# to print it to console.
df.to_csv(sys.stdout, header=None)
```

Result:

```
2011-03-28,2298,28
2011-03-29,2322,22
2011-03-30,2309,09
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor! I ran your exact code, and I get: "raise Exception('item names overlap')". I believe the cause is that both JSON responses use 'value' as the index name. If I change the index name to 'value2' in the second call response, then your code works.  Is there a way to handle this inside pandas, or should I munge the data before using pd?

Comment: @user2726872 You can handle it by renaming the column. I updated the code. You probably use a really old version of pandas, since the new versions can handle duplicate names.

Comment: I now get an error that 'inplace' is an keyword.  My problem must be old pandas.  I installed 'python-pandas' from Ubuntu's repository, which must be very old.  I'll work on updating pandas instead of fixing obsolete code.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2726872 Yes definitely. The latest ubuntu ships with 0.10.1 version of pandas, the latest version is 0.12. The easiest way to update is to build from source or to install Anaconda or Canopy.

Comment: I just used 'sudo pip install pandas --update' instead of relying on the included pandas from the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS repository.  It's working now.  Thanks again for the help and prompt responses.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a database (like SQLite).  Create a table with the first column as the date and one column for each API.  Allow NULLs in the API columns.

Then, for each API, read the data and update/insert (upsert) just that one column for the specified date.  This can be completely independent of the CSV generation.

Generating a CSV should be trivial once the data is in the database.

Updating historical data will be much easier with an index on the date column.